# Объясните логику тернарного оператора в данном примере

Tags: c#

```
if( i!= 0? i%2 ==0: false) 
  //......
```

В данном примере получается 2 проверки на верность идёт?
Если значение i не равно 0,то даст true, и выполняется выражение

```
i%2 == 0
```

Но если оно не делится без остатка, то в этом выражении false,? И перейдет к значению
, т.е выражению под номер 3.

```
false
```

Или если в выраж 2 false то к 3 выражению мы не переходим?

Comment: «И перейдет к значению , т.е выражению под номер 3» — нет. Просто вернёт `false`.

Comment: А разве тернарный оператор используют в if? Я видел(и использую сам) его только при присваивании или возвращении результата из метода.

Comment: Если i == 0, то выполнится  `: false`. Вообще смысл всего `if(...)` такой -- если i не ноль и i четное, то выполнить операторы под if, или иными словами (правильный выбор зависит от физического смысла задачи), если i равно нули или i нечетно, то ничего деллать не надо.

Comment: @Lapish ну Шилдт видимо практикует такое, у него написано следующее(Присваивать переменной результат выполнения оператора ? совсем не обязатель­
но. Например, значение, которое дает оператор ?, можно использовать в качестве аргу­
мента при вызове метода. А если все выражения в операторе ? относятся к типу bool,
то такой оператор может заменить собой условное выражение в цикле или операторе if)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще это в точности соответствует такому оператору `if`:

```cs
if (i != 0 && i%2 == 0)
...
```

Зачем было так запутывать логику - непонятно. Обычно `true` и `false` нет необходимости писать при вычислении булевой логики. Условие либо выполняется, либо не выполняется.

Comment: Как много вопросов к Шилдту, и так мало ответов

Comment: Вероятно кто-то рефакторил, что-то убрал, а структуру оставил как было

Comment: @gachi_muchenik: Шилдт ужасен, выбросьте или подарите своему врагу.

Comment: @VladD Сначала начал читать Библию с# Фленова, какой то ужас, главу не дочитал, а Шилдта решил потому что по нему раньше  учил C++. Может вы что то посоветуете, потому что у всех мнения расходятся, говорят что после Шилдта приходится переучиватся, но как база идеально. Может что для начала посоветуете?

Comment: @gachi_muchenik: В [описании метки [c#]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) я когда-то поместил ссылку на список литературы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105